# Creating HTML Table in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-scope

```
var str1 = "Sarah";
var str2 = "Tom";
var strTable = "<table style='width:100%'><tr><th>"+ str1 +"</th><th>"+ str2 +"</th> <th>Age</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td><td>50</td></tr></table>";

$scope.rTable= strTable;
```

I am trying to pass HTML code in `$Scope.rTable` but instead of rendering the table it shows the HTML code as it is in the output.

i.e.

```
<table style='width:100%'><tr><th>Sarah</th><th>Tom</th> <th>Age</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td><td>50</td></tr></table>
```

I want it like:

[image]

Comment: use `ng-bind-html="rTable"` with [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) module. Or compile it with `$compile` (in a directive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use ng-bind-html and $sce.**

Controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {

  var str1 = "Sarah";
  var str2 = "Tom";
  var strTable = "<table style='width:100%'><tr><th>" + str1 + "</th><th>" + str2 + "</th> <th>Age</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td><td>50</td></tr></table>";
  $scope.rTable = $sce.trustAsHtml(strTable);
});
```

HTML

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-bind-html="rTable"></div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Its a improper way to code.
The code should be like

**In Controller**

```
$scope.str1 = "Sarah";
$scope.str2 = "Tom";
```

**In HTML**

*Considering your controller name as DemoController*

```
<body ng-controller="DemoController">
<table style='width:100%'>
    <tr><th> {{str1}} </th>
        <th> {{str2}} </th>
        <th>Age</th> 
    </tr> 
</table>
</body>
```

And if your data is huge its recommended to use an Array of Object with ng-repeat. you can read it here -> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Thanks, But what I wanted to do is not possible like this, I needed a way that creates a table on run time.

Comment: Can you please explain the scenario why do you need to create table dynamically?